# Alternative to intel XDK?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I am using XDK to do iOS build and Android build for the hybrid app. It works great! But XDK "retires" the build feature in favor of IoT.

So is there any alternative to XDK iOS and Android build?

I am just looking for the build feature and not so much as automate app creation or using their UI widget, debugger or their framework. Just an online iOS and Android build.

Cordova CLI is their recommendation alternative, but you need a "mac" to do an iOS build, and Abobe Online PhoneGap build is not so good and not free.

Comment: Does anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: PhoneGap Build does offer a free option which works quite well > https://build.phonegap.com/plans < as long as you do not have any custom Cordova plugins (private plugins) and are not creating large apps (>50MB). Most apps fit into this category.

Comment: You would need a Mac to do an iOS build anyway

Answer (score 0):

Note that [the "Cordova Package Build" export tool](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/build-xdk-app-with-phonegap-cordova-cli) on the XDK Build tab provides you with the ability to export a ZIP file that can be built using PhoneGap Build (or Cordova CLI). Using that export feature, you can continue to manage your build settings, add or remove plugins, and perform debugging with the Simulate tab and the Test tab.

> Only the XDK build system will be retired at the end of June. The rest
>   of the XDK, as you see it today (v3977), will continue to be usable
>   after the build system has been retired. The build tiles will
>   disappear when the build system is retired, but the "Cordova Build
>   Package" tool that allows you to export a project for use with
>   PhoneGap Build or Cordova CLI will still work (it does not rely on the
>   build backend to function).